# Using Interlocked

Tags: .net, performance, multithreading, interlocked

Is this code thread-safe? or put it this way:

**Is there anyway to call GetIt() and that GetIt() will return the same number to 2 different threads**

```
Private Shared hitCount As Long = 1

Public Shared Function GetIt() As Long
     Threading.Interlocked.Increment(hitCount)
     DoSomethingQuick(hitCount)
     Return hitCount
End Function
```

It seems like it's possible, then am I supposed to use `Interlocked.Read()` or lock the whole thing in one block?

Comment: I think you're going to hit an overflow exception once you reach `Integer.MaxValue`? `hitCount` is a Long but you're returning an Integer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes there is a possibility:

1. Thread 1 runs `Threading.Interlocked.Increment(hitCount)`
2. Thread 2 runs `Threading.Interlocked.Increment(hitCount)`
3. Thread 1 runs `Return hitCount`
4. Thread 2 runs `Return hitCount`

In steps 3 and 4, hitCount will be the same value.

But the fix is easy Interlocked.Increment returns the incremented value, so just change your code to:

```
Private Shared hitCount As Long = 1L

Public Shared Function GetIt() As Long
     Return Threading.Interlocked.Increment(hitCount)
End Function
```

**Edit**
Or now based on your edit, you have a pretty bit timing hole.  Anyway then this is what you want:

```
Public Shared Function GetIt() As Long
     Dim localHitCount As Long = Threading.Interlocked.Increment(hitCount)
     Console.Writeline("Something, something....")
     Return localHitCount 
End Function
```

**Edit**
Then do this (which is exactly what Michael suggested below)

```
Private Shared hitCount As Long = 1L

Public Shared Function GetIt() As Long
     Dim localHitCount As Long = Threading.Interlocked.Increment(hitCount)
     DoSomethingQuick(localHitCount )
     Return localHitCount 
End Function
```

Comment: :) I didn't know that it was returning the final value, nice one.

Comment: Just updated the code to make same with my original code (sorry I badly wrote the sample code). AFAIK in this updated code I have to wrap the whole thing with a lock.

Comment: You could just cache the return value from Interlocked.Increment and use that in the call to DoSomethingQuick and the return.

Comment: Thanks Michael! Darn! Why didn't I think that? :) That was obvious wasn't it :D

Comment: You don't need but the whole thing is a lock, unless you are relying on hitCount not changing at all during the run, rather than just ensuring that you have a unique value.

Comment: @shf301: Firstly, `localHitCount` should be a `Long`, not an `int`; otherwise this method could throw an overflow exception when `hitCount` exceeds `Integer.MaxValue`. Secondly, you seem to have mixed C# and VB in your code...

Comment: @shf301: Actually, I just realized I could edit it for you :)